# string http response != same string in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building a web app that uses Angularjs. In one of my controllers I make a call to the backend that returns the current login status of the user.

```
   $http.get('http://localhost:3000/status')
     .success(function(status) {
       if (status == 'internal') {
         // do stuff...
```

Even when the requests responds with status equal to 'internal', (status == 'internal') evaluates to false. To test this a bit I put

```
  $http.get('http://localhost:3000/status')
    .success(function(status) {
      console.log(typeof status)
      console.log(status)
      console.log(status == "internal")
```

which prints

```
    string 
    "internal" 
    false
```

Any Ideas about what could be going wring here?

Comment: what happens when you use 3 equality marks? `(status === 'internal')` also, can there maybe be some extra whitespace or something like that?

Comment: make sure no extra white space being sent...check length of status vs length of your test string

Comment: Are you returning `internal` or `"internal"` (with quotes).  I ask because `console.log(typeof status)` would display as a string but you didn't double quote that in your output.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: BTW...why don't you send json?

Comment: `console.log(status.length)` and `console.log(status.split(''))` should help shed some light on it.

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks that helped. It was actually returning a string with quotes inside of it like '"internal"'

Answer (score 7):

Sorry, this is only a valid answer if you're using Chrome. It looks like Firefox *will* wrap strings in quotes on the console.

---

Your string has extra quotes around it. `console.log(string)` won't show quotes. Observe:

```
console.log("what")
what
```

The only way you're seeing `"internal"` instead of `internal` is if you have extra quotes around your string.

Answer (score 2):

This should be what you're looking for:

```
console.log(status == '"internal"');
```